# Importing p5 into a Vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, p5.js

I added the p5 library into the dom like so...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>App</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.10/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.10/addons/p5.dom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So technically I should be able to grab it via `window` variable within my Vue code...

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>Hey my app!</h1>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'app',
    mounted() {
        console.log(window.p5) // it's found
        window.p5.createCanvas(640, 480);
    },
}
</script>
```

Yet error logs show:
`TypeError: window.p5.createCanvas is not a function`. After logging `window.p5`, I can see that it's there. Just not `createCanvas()`. Which makes me think it's not fully there to begin with. Has anyone experienced this problem? How can I successfully import p5 and make use of it in my Vue app?

Comment: Any clue about extending p5 with p5.dom? Been struggling with this for hours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just randomly call the `createCanvas()` function. You have to do it after the `setup()` function is called.

More info here: [Why can't I assign variables using p5 functions and variables before `setup()`?](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#why-cant-i-assign-variables-using-p5-functions-and-variables-before-setup)

To fix your problem, you either need to put your call inside the `setup()` function, or you need to use on-demand instance mode (as explained in the above link) or instance mode (as explained [here](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode)).